# Magento 2 : what is the use of getFacetedData() in category filter?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

Magento 2 Category layered navigatoin,

In magento category layered navigation content comes from below file

`vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php`

In this file, inside `_getItemsData()` function one line,

```
$optionsFacetedData = $productCollection->getFacetedData('category');
```

I want to know what is the use of `getFacetedData('category')` in magento.

Answer (score 1):

**getFacetedData** only exists in the product "**fulltext**" collection,

i.e. for search results and category pages.

It returns information for the layered navigation, as returned by the search engine (MySQL).

For each of these, it contains the number of results like :

**price ranges**

**categories**

**filterable attributes**